# WP Bodymovin plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins

Im currently working on a wordpress project where I've created animations via Bodymovin.
Im using the plugin 'WP Bodymovin' to echo out the animations via the shortcode-generator.

It all works fine untill I enable the setting `'autoplay_"true"'`, then it fails to render the animation.

Full php code is as follows:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[bodymovin anim_id="133" lazyload="true" autoplay_viewport="true"]' ); ?>
```

Does anyone have experience with this plugin and/or perhaps the same issue Im having?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a link to the page with the problem, or can you recreate it publicly?

Comment: Im running the installation locally via xampp. Unsure as to how I would go about to run it publicly.

Comment: Yes I have created one here design-studio.io , you can also create this easily. https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-web please find the doc.

Comment: You can find more help here : http://airbnb.io/lottie/web/web.html

Comment: @leetajz does the animation work in the preview in the WP admin?

Comment: @leetajz I just tested this myself, it's working fine with `autoplay_viewport="true"`

Comment: @markmoxx Yes it works fine in the preview, and also work just fine when I set autoplay_viewport to false. Are you using the shortcode generator or did you do a workaround?

Comment: I used the shortcode given in the animation post edit page, on a standard post page. Tested on a fresh install of WP 4.9.8 and 5.0.0 - all fine. Check your console for javascript errors, and isolate the plugin by turning all others off - another plugin could be interfering with it.

Comment: Did you get this solved?

Comment: Yes problem is solved. Thank you. There was a jquery script tag causing the error.